# Show two tables in activeadmin index do

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, ruby-2.1, paper-trail-gem

In my application I have following code:

```
index do
  sortable_handle_column
  column :key
  column :text do |post|
    text(post.text)
  end
  column :visible
  default_actions
end
```

Now I want to add a new table to the index do. But if I just add following code inside index do, before the sortable_handle_column it does not work as I want.

```
panel "Recent activity" do
  table_for PaperTrail::Version.order('id desc').where("item_type = ?", "user").limit(5) do
    //code for table
  end
end
```

Both of the tables is shown but I can't decide in what order they is presented.

First is the Header "Recent activity", after that comes the key, text and visible columns from the first table. After that comes the content from my table_for PaperTrail::Version.

Any idea on how to solve this, how do I  do to  have two tables on the same page.

I have seen that some uses the code below, is there anyway to do it for rows instead of columns

```
columns do
  column do
    // code first column
  end
  column do
    // code second column
  end
end
```